# how many pairs of plaintext-ciphertext are needed before we break AES?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis

Imagine a set of words ($plaintext$) each are encrypted using AES-ECB mode and due to some leakage in the system an attacker could gain access to some pairs of $plaintext$ and $ciphertext$. But once the attacker got bunch of such pairs he cannot further ask the oracle for any other pairs. So in reality how many such pairs of $plaintext$ and $ciphertext$ are needed to crack the $key$.

Here each input $|plaintext| < 128$ bits.

Comment: As far as I know, you can have all the plaintext/ciphertext pairs (there is a finite number, thanks to the restriction in the question) and still not be able to extract the AES key.

Comment: @mikeazo ...in reasonable time, that is. The question did not make any restriction on the running time of an attack (but admittedly does not make *too* much sense without that implicit addition).

Comment: @yyyyyyy, yeah, that is what I was thinking too. Also, with reason amount of memory.

Comment: @yyyyyyy I think the expected life time of our Sun is reasonable enough. Otherwise: the expected life time of the universe?

Comment: so does this mean , we cannot infer the key in any reasonable amount of time ?